# MySQL intelligent default value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm adding stuff to a MySQL table, and each item has a `position` that it shows up in my system like a question number.

I could find out what the largest `position` is before adding a new question, `+1` it, and then add it - but I was wondering if there's a more intelligent way that doesn't require a second query.

Something like `INSERT INTO questions (id, position) values (0, MAX(position))`.

This field is not the primary key, auto_increment is of no use to this situation.

I cannot use `position` as the key, because the key relates to many other things, and the `position` can be changed at any time.

I am a pretty confident MySQL query writer, so please don't offer any suggestions other than the question asked - I know of plenty of alternatives, this is just a syntax question.

I'm sure you get my drift!

Cheers.

Comment: Like, an auto-incrementing index perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the table holds questions for multiple surveys so that wouldn't work well for me.

Comment: You could always do a sub query on your insert, and add 1 to the `COUNT`.

Comment: Another option would be to simply not put in a question number and use the index as the ordering qualifier. Then renumber using the logical position in the result set when queried.  Essentially, renumber your questions as you pull a specific set from the database.  It would keep them in order and it would be one less field you'd need in your database.

Comment: Question with ID of 5 is a multiple choice question, and has 5 answer options related to it from a different table. If I move question 5 to question 8, those answer options get applied to an entirely inappropriate question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) like most other folk do?

This is the intelligent way because it concurrency safe.

Comment: My `position` field is not the key though, and I need a separate key because position can be changed at any time

Comment: Use a separate table then that has an an FK which is the PK of the current table with another key. However, if it can be changed, then what happens if someone inserts 967 and an update happens of 42 to 1432? Is it unique?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to change the field properties within MySQL, meaning let MySql do the work without providing input.

`TABLE TableName CHANGE position position INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Now when inserting, do not provide any values for this field.

`INSERT INTO questions (var1, var2) values (val1,val2)`

MySQL will automatically increment the position value. You can set current counter as well as reset if need be. This way you are not running any quarries at all.

Comment: Except that you're only allowed one auto_increment field, and that has to be the primary key.

Comment: auto_increment field does NOT have to be primary key.

Comment: `MySQL said: 
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key `

Comment: You can have a non-key auto-increment column in MyISAM, but not in InnoDB.

Comment: Oh, okay, the error correct, you can only have one auto increment field per table, but again, it does not have to be primary key.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
INSERT INTO questions (id, position) SELECT 0, MAX(position)+1 FROM questions;
```

Obviously, you will need to handle the 0 value, as in set it for something appropriate, i just copied that value off your example.

You could also create a stored procedure to use in the query, or even have a trigger which determines the MAX(position), adds one and stores it in your newly created row.

Quite alot of options there, I would go for the above solution though (with a index on position)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to set a default value to a specific calculation, it seems.